# Text Fields Extraction Tools Recommendation

Tags: data-format

The Problem: I have emails coming through and I want to parse few fields from this emails to save it as structured data , can use regex if I just have one or two structures but I have a lot of them so I am looking for library then accepts text input + rules like then will look for each rule and try to extract the required field based on the defined steps Example:

Text Input:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur Name : John Doe adipiscing elit. Mauris at ipsum quis quam iaculis luctus. Nam vitae accumsan dolor, at maximus risus. Aliquam interdum finibus erat at tincidunt. Age : 25 In ullamcorper sapien sit amet molestie faucibus. Pellentesque leo massa, egestas eu ullamcorper id, sollicitudin at justo. Etiam sit amet ornare ante, vitae facilisis lacus. Etiam a orci vel mauris elementum sollicitudin.

Rules (JSON Or XML):

Remove Empty Lines
Field Name : Name
Something like that a good example is mailparser.io , you set your parsing rules and then the platform extract the data based on your rules

Comment: you'll need to build a parser and model for the job, here is an example: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/86249/94887

Comment: Thanks @sb0709 , you are right i started to write my own parser